# How to add CSS file in Jhipster

Tags: css, jhipster

I would like to add my own css file into a Jhipster project.
I put those files in src\main\webapp\assets\styles\

The gruntfile.js should be able to add those files into the depencies am I right ?
But they added ... any idea why ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add the gulpfile and I will help you.

Answer (score -1):

Yes if you put a file into this directory, it will belong to your project (that's kind of obvious, as it's the CSS folder of your project).

I guess that what you want to do is use this file inside your index.html file. The normal `grunt wiredep` command works only if you use Bower, which is our JavaScript/CSS dependency package manager. In your case, you are just adding the file manually, so you are not using Bower: just add your file inside the index.html file, as would do in a normal project, outside of the Bower tags, and you will be able to use it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Yes I indeed add it manually to the folder, so I did in the index.html file. I know that grunt wiredep only add the dependecies of bower. I was just hopping that grunt would also manage those files too :) (Since jhipster is so magic !!) I checked the gruntfile.js though, and I was wondering if uglify includes those files too ?